# HTML PHP - After SubmitOnlineForm doesnt Login

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project and building an Html PHP Website with MySQL.
I tried to change the structure of my Project and added a Switch Menue in my index.php where I include all the sides.

Now all my Login and Register Sites are not working anymore. For Example: If I go to login and submit the form I will be redirected to the index.php and nothing happens.

can you help me?

Thats the Switch in my index.html

```
    <?php
    
    // All PHP-Pages are included using "include"
    switch ($menu) {
        case 'impressum':
            include 'sites/impressum.php';
            break;
        case 'Help':
            include 'sites/Help.php';
            break;
        case 'ManageNews':
            include 'sites/ManageNews.php';
            break;
        case 'register':
            include 'sites/register.php';
            break;
        case 'Profile':
            include 'sites/profile.php';
            break;
        case 'ServiceTicket':
            include 'sites/ServiceTicket.php';
            break;
        case 'reportIssue':
            include 'sites/reportIssue.php';
            break;
        case 'userdata':
            include 'config/userdata.php';
            break;
        case 'editProfilepassword':
            include 'sites/editProfilepassword.php';
            break;
        case 'Logout':
            include 'sites/logout.php';
            break;
        case 'login':
            include 'sites/login.php';
            break;
            
    }
    
    
    if ($menu == 'home') {
        
        ?>
```

sites/nav.php:

```
<div class="container-nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
        <a class="position-absolute top-0 end-0 logo" href="./index.php" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="./Bilder/logo_trans.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" width="150" class="d-inline- 
          block align-top">
      <span class="hidden">Web</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
    target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="./index.php?menu=home">Home</a>
        </li>
  
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.php?menu=login">LogIn</a>
        </li>';
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thats the login.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
    header("location: ../index.php?menu=home");
    exit;
}
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";


// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Check if username is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else {
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    


    // Validate credentials
    if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)) {
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, role, status FROM users WHERE username = ?";
            
      
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $hashed_password, $role, $status);
                    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
                            $_SESSION["status"] = $status;
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            if($_SESSION["status"] =="active"){
                                header("Location: ../index.php?menu=home");
                            } else{header("Location: ../index.php?menu=home");}
                        } else {
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My First Page</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100;200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
    <div name="page-content">
        
        <section class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($login_err)) {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
                    }
                    
                    ?>
                    <form class="row gap-4" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have `?>` before the `switch` statement? If it were really this way, the interpreter wouln’t interpret it as PHP anymore. And are you sure your server executes the PHP code in .html file?

Comment: yes, i just forgett to copy it here. I edited my post were the hole switch is included. Also. if i go directy to the login form (enter it in the url and not with the link in the navigation i can login) it only doesnt work if i click in the navigation on login and try to submit

Answer (score 0):

Check what this line results to in the browser:

```
<form class="row gap-4" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

I guess it results to

```
...action="index.php"...
```

an not to

```
...action="index.php?menu=login"...
```

So you should change it to

```
<form class="row gap-4" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>?menu=login" method="post">
```

or add a hidden field in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="menu" value="login" />
```

By the way: you might consider to switch PHP to safe mode and use

```
 switch ($_GET['menu']) {
```

or (if you add the hidden field to the form)

```
 switch ($_POST['menu']) {
```

instead of

```
 switch ($menu) {
```

Comment: you are right. I added "?menu=login" to my action. But the problem is - i know jump to "http://localhost/dashboard/". If i go back i am logged in. But i dont understand why it redirects me to the xampp dashboard

Comment: Maybe also something like "sites/" is missing in the action-tag of the form. Check in the sourcecode in the brwoser what "action" is and what it sould be. The URL musst be the same like click on "login" in your menue, or you can try to leave it empty which means like "post the data to the url where I am now".